# Synchronizing a Cipher

Tags: java, replace

I am creating an application which simply scrambles a string, and can put it back together. It follows a simple cipher. I am using code like this:

```
String oldstr = "Hello"

String newstr = old.replace("e", "l").replace("l", "t");
```

I only put a tiny bit because if I wrote out the entire thing, it would be huge.

On to the problem. The way the program works, it first replaces the "e" in "Hello" with an "l", turning the string into "Hlllo". Then it replaces the "l"s with "t"s. However, I don't want the "e" to eventually become an "t", since then I cant turn it back into the original. The way I want this application to work, the outcome would be, "Hltto". Is there a way that I can synchronize the application so that it will do this?

**EDIT:**

I am not looking for answers that only work for this scenario (in my actual application I have 26 characters being changed).

Comment: First replace the L with T, and then replace the E with L, and you will get your output, however that only works on this one scenario

Answer (score 2):

A cipher should be **reversible**.

That means, all operations must be reversible. A replace operation is not because it maps two different characters to one. (yours maps both 'e' and 'l' to 'l')

You'd have to build a table of what each character becomes, and change each character based on that table. For example:

> a → ...
>   b → ...
>   c → ...
>   d → ...
>   e → l
>   ...
>   l → t
>   ...

Be sure that there are no duplicates on the right side.

Then iterate over each character in the string and build a new string.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(old.length());

for (char c : oldStr.toCharArray())
    sb.append( replaceChar(c) );

newStr = db.toString().
```

The function `replaceChar(c)` can be as simple as a look-up table, or for more coding convenience, can be a 26-entry switch statement, or (as in real cryptography) a key-dependent mathematical function.

Also, be aware of what should happen between upper and lower case letters and what happens to other characters (like 'à', 'ÿ', '気', ...)

Comment: I'm not that experienced with java, so I would appreciate if you could give me some example code (maybe a 2-entry switch statement to show what you mean) because when I tried it out, I got an error.

Comment: @nousername This is you opportunity to gain experience with Java, that is what we all did, studied, wrote code, debugged, learned.

Answer (score 1):

Consider processing a string char-by-char using a `Map` for replacements:

```
// replacement map
static final Map<Character, Character> REPLACEMENTS = new HashMap<>();

// fill up replacements
static {
   for (String r : "el,lt,te,ab,ba".split(","))     // add all replacement pairs you need
       REPLACEMENTS.put(r.charAt(0), r.charAt(1));  // e→l, l→t, t→e, a→b, ...
}

// encoding method
static public String encode(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : input.toCharArray())
        sb.append(REPLACEMENTS.getOrDefault(c, c)); 
    return sb.toString();
}
```

To check how it's working, call:

```
System.out.println(encode("Hello"));   // Hltto
```

Comment: I'm not that experienced at java, so I'm completely confused. A working example would be nice. Thanks for the effort you put into the code.

Comment: @nousername now (after a small edit) this code works perfetly. You may run it in debug mode step-by-step to see how it works (by the way, it is very simple). `Map` is extremely common datastructure used in Java, as well as `StringBuilder`, so I hope this will improve your Java experience

Answer (score 0):

One way It can be accomplished is to have a Bitmap/bitstring/array of binary values. Call it whatever you want. So that each bit represent a letter. Initially before ciphering all bits are 0. Then when you change some letter you go to the bit array and flip corresponding bit. This way you know that it was changed so next pass will change only letters that correspond to 0 in bit array. 
Or you  can do all your ciphering in just one pass.

```
for (int i = 0; i < oldstring.length; i++) {
     switch (oldstring.charAt(i)) {
      .....
       .
       .
       .
      .....
      default: do nothing.
      }
}
```

Comment: When I tried the switch statement, it gives me an error. I'm not that experienced with java, so I'm probably doing something wrong. I would like it if you could give me a working example (maybe just 2 entries in the switch statement).